# jQuery - Run function only on mobile

Tags: jquery

The function converts the `ul` into a `select / option input` which I only want to happen while in mobile. If the screen size is > 479, then don't apply the function (i.e would remove the `.option` class and disable both `click` events).

How do I update the function to only apply when the screen size is `<=479` on load / resize?

```js
//
// ul-select
// https://github.com/zgreen/ul-select
//

$.fn.ulSelect = function() {
  var ul = $(this);

  if (!ul.hasClass("option")) {
    ul.addClass("option");
  }
  // SVG arrow
  var arrow = '<div class="icon icon--caret"></div>';

  $(".tab__menu--main")
    .find(".tab__btn.w--current", this)
    .addClass("active")
    .append(arrow);

  $(this).on("click", ".tab__btn", function(event) {
    // Remove div#selected if it exists
    if ($("#selected--option").length) {
      $("#selected--option").remove();
    }
    ul.before('<div id="selected--option">');
    var selected = $("#selected--option");
    $(".tab__btn .icon--caret", ul).remove();
    ul.toggleClass("active");
    // Remove active class from any <li> that has it...
    ul.children().removeClass("active");
    // And add the class to the <li> that gets clicked
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    //Find and append the variables for each:
    var selectedText = $(this).find(".tab__text").text();

    if (ul.hasClass("active")) {
      selected.text(selectedText).addClass("active").append(arrow);
    } else {
      selected.text("").removeClass("active");
      $(".tab__btn.active", ul).append(arrow);
    }
  });
  // Close the faux select menu when clicking outside it
  $(document).on("click", function(event) {
    if ($(".tab__menu--main.option").length) {
      if (!$(".tab__menu--main.option").has(event.target).length == 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        $(".tab__menu--main.option").removeClass("active");
        $("#selected--option").removeClass("active").text("");
        $(".icon--caret").remove();
        $(".tab__menu--main.option .tab__btn.active").append(arrow);
      }
    }
  });
};

// Run
$(".tab__menu--main").ulSelect();
```

```css
.tab__menu {
  border: 3px solid;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.tab__btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .tab__btn {
    display: none;
  }
}

.option {
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tab__btn.active {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aaa;
  color: #111;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.option.active {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.option.active .tab__btn {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: block;
}

.option.active .tab__btn:hover {
  background: #0074d9;
}

.option.active .tab__btn.active {
  background: #40a6ff;
}

.option.active .tab__btn.active:hover {
  background: #0074d9;
}

#selected--option {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #111;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: auto;
}

#selected--option.active {
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aaa;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#selected--option.active>.icon--caret {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.icon--caret {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <ul class="tab__menu tab__menu--main">
    <li class="tab__btn">
      <div class="tab__text">Option 1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="tab__btn w--current">
      <div class="tab__text">Option 2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="tab__btn">
      <div class="tab__text">Option 3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can have both items, show one on desktop and show the other on mobile, if there are behaviour changes which should apply for mobile and desktop, then you would need to update the other item(not the trigger ing one) to match. Ideally you would have some kind of framework to detect what screen size you are in

Answer (score 0):

You can use [matchMedia API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) it's JavaScript version of media query where you ask if the media match.

With this you can use:

```
let mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 479px)');

if (mql.matches) {
   // add select
}
```

**NOTE:** Good practice would be also to make this responsive maybe not add the select dynamically but hide and show it when media change. That way you can make this the same when you test it in browser with responsive debugger (Chrome feature). With show hide you can use normal CSS based media query to show hide the select.

Comment: I need to be able to revert back or "disable" the function when the screen size is greater than 479px. I want to only apply the function to the list when in mobile (479px)

Comment: @KyleJohn not sure if I understand. You have else in if, you have two cases one when on mobile when width if smaller then 479 and if you add else it will be executed when the screen is larger. Also is I've written if want responsive better idea is to hide show two different UI for different sizes you can do that with css media queries.

Comment: The function converts the list into a select / option input which I only want to happen while in mobile. If the screen size is >=479, then don't apply the function.

Comment: @KyleJohn I have no idea what else I can tell you put the code into `if (mql.matches) { / HERE */ }` and it will be executed only on mobile, what else you expect me to tell you? And as I've written in NOTE it will not work if you want that to happen responsively and change while you resize the window (for instance in Chrome devtools) for this you need to hide the select and show hide it unless you want to keep removing and inserting the select while the size change (which make no sense IMHO).

Comment: Your solution works however I do need it to happen responsively like you said.

Comment: @KyleJohn once again you can't do that in JavaScript if you want responsive, you need to always create the select and hide/show it responsively, it's waste of resources to delete and create the select responsively in JavaScript, that's way you should do this in CSS. You already have media query in your CSS so you should be able to create this yourself.